# Are there any fungible, but indivisible, ERC tokens?

Tags: tokens

Are there any ETH tokens that are fungible, but also indivisible?

I'm learning about ERC-1155, and one of the common use case examples is video game items. For example, your game might have 200 swords. They're fungible with each other, but are indivisible.

Digital currencies are fungible, but they're also divisible. For example, I can buy 0.12 ETH. I'd like to find a currency that is fungible and indivisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ETH-based coins are fungible and indivisible, but they aren't presented that way.

If you create an ERC-20 smart contract, you set the total number of tokens **and** how many decimal points you want to use.

Say an altcoin has chosen to use 4 decimal places of accuracy. If someone buys 12.8462 ALTCOIN, they're actually buying 128,462 of the individual, fungible tokens.

This seems like skeumorphism. It would be weird for someone to buy 8 billion of a new ICO at launch. Most communities adjust the decimal points so you're buying 800 COIN instead.